# How to output the top $k$ "diverse" strings from a set of $n$ strings

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Suppose I am given n strings of equal length. I want to output a subset of them of size k such that they are as diverse as possible, for example, if n=3 and k=2
Strings: AAABC, AAACB, XYZWR

I would output {XYZWR,AAABC} or {XYZWR,AAACB} (but not {AAABC,AAACB}) because they are the most "diverse". Is there a known algorithm to solve such a problem?

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Comment: You need to give a more precise definition of the "diversity" of a set

Comment: I thought about finding the longest consecutive sub string of one string in another and giving that pair a weight of "diversity", then repeat this for all possible pairs n(n-1)/2 of them, then output pairs with the most contribution to the diversity (i.e. optimization problem of the diversity function)

Comment: This sounds like you are just trying to permutate the strings. Take a look at, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap's_algorithm

Comment: By diverse, I mean that 1) As many letters are used as possible and 2) the ordering of individual letters don't match too much. For example ABC and CAB are a little diverse because of (2) but not too diverse because of (1) while XYZ and ABC satisfy both (1) and (2)